# Grails installation error "classfile_constants.h"

Tags: windows, grails

I'm having problems during installation of Grails on Windows 8 machine. I followed steps on http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/gettingStarted.html#downloadingAndInstalling but when I type 'grails' into command line, I get this weird error
**\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\include\classfile_constants.h was unexpected at this time.**

Does anybody know what's going on here?

Thank you
Matthew

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps with your problem but I got that error this morning when trying to upgrade my netbeans project to the netbeans ide 8.0 that uses grails-2.4.0.  I changed it to use the previous version - grails-2.0.4 and it fixed the error.

Comment: Sorry - meant to give you this link.  You can not run upgrade to 2.4.0 from 2.3.? http://grails.org/doc/2.4.x/guide/upgradingFrom23.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Mine was caused by having a parenthesis in my JAVA_HOME path.  I moved my java install to another folder and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Grails version 2.4 or above you will need to install JDK 1.7 or above. Grails from version 2.0.1 on needs JDK 1.7 or above.